# How to expose aspnet core web application to local network through IIS?

Tags: ssl, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I am current working through a Windows VM on a Mac via VMWare Fusion 10. I am attempting to set up a ASPNET Core Application that connects to my MSSQL database and exposes functionality through REST API. I'm trying to expose my localhost server so that I can make requests from remote computers on the local network.

I was able to connect to the correct IP/Port from another computer but I was using HTTPS and didn't have a valid SSL certificate for anything except localhost. What is the proper way to set up a secure ASPNET Core web service accessible by the local network?

Comment: Which version of ASP.NET core are you using? Also, are you able to access using machine name or domain name on local network instead of IP?

Comment: You can create a self signed Certificate on IIS since you are hosting in Windows